# How to resume session - ejabberd

Tags: ios, ejabberd, xmppframework

For session resumption I am following xep-0198( stream management in XMPP framework). It only works for 300 seconds. If the user doesn't open chat app for more than 300 seconds, the connection lost automatically, even if i increased the time out interval.

i made the following to yml file:

```
listen: 
  - 
    port: 5222
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    resend_on_timeout: if_offline
    stream_management: true
    resume_timeout: 10000
    max_resume_timeout: 10000
```

In code:(Swift) while login to app

```
xmppStreamManagement = XMPPStreamManagement(storage: XMPPStreamManagementMemoryStorage(), dispatchQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
xmppStreamManagement?.autoResume = true
xmppStreamManagement?.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
xmppStreamManagement?.activate(stream)
```

After authentication:

```
xmppStreamManagement?.enable(withResumption: true, maxTimeout: 10000)

func canResumeStream() -> Bool{
        return true
    }

    func xmppStreamManagement(_ sender: XMPPStreamManagement!, wasEnabled enabled: DDXMLElement!){
        print("enabled")
    }

    func xmppStreamManagement(_ sender: XMPPStreamManagement!, wasNotEnabled failed: DDXMLElement!){
        print("not enabled")
    }

    func supportsStreamManagement() -> Bool{
        return true
    }
```

I got the following result from server:

```
<enabled xmlns="urn:xmpp:sm:3" resume="true" max="10000" id="g2gCbQAAABY1NzQ5MzQwOTgwNjk2OTY4NTcxMjE4aANiAAAF0WIACjagYRg="/>
```

But session expires if i keep user idle more than 5 minutes. Can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: you have to enable mod_ping on server side or ping to server on  an  interval otherwise TCP/IP connection get closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XMPPPingModule (XEP-0199: XMPP Ping) to keep your session alive.

Example:

```
let  xmppPing = XMPPPing()
xmppPing?.respondsToQueries = true
xmppPing?.activate(stream)

let xmppAutoPing = XMPPAutoPing()
xmppAutoPing?.pingInterval = (yourTimeInterval) * 60
xmppAutoPing?.pingTimeout = pingTimeOutTime
xmppAutoPing?.activate(stream)
```